# Weighted averages and total scores by group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following population data:

[image]

I'm trying to get the following `Total score` for each `combination of timeperiod-district-region`  in my dataset:

[image]

I've done the calculation in Excel but am struggling to implement it in Microsoft SQL Server:

[image]

I've tried implementing everything from joins to window calculations but struggling to get beyond the first step.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    select w1.TimePeriod, w1.Region, w1.District, w1.Population/sum(w2.Population)
    from table w1 INNER JOIN table w2
        on w1.TimePeriod=w2.TimePeriod AND w1.Region=w2.Region AND w1.District=w2.District 
    group by w1.TimePeriod, w1.Region, w1.District
```

Eeeor:

> Column 'table.Population' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help to get me started will be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select timeperiod, district, region,
       sum(population * score) / sum(population)
from t
group by timeperiod, district, region;
```

You don't need to count the total population for this calculation in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
,sum([Population]) OVER () AS allpopulation
,( cast ( [Population] AS FLOAT) / cast((sum([Population]) OVER () )AS FLOAT)) AS popweigted
,round ( ( cast ( [Population] AS FLOAT) / cast((sum([Population]) OVER () )AS FLOAT)) * [Score] , 2) as "pop_weighted*score" FROM [dbo].[table]
```

check the result here
[image]